# How to write HTML code inside PHP

Tags: php, html

My PHP code begins with the `?php` tag and ends with the `?` tag and my file extension is `php`. If I want to write part of my PHP code inside HTML, what is the general way of doing it?

For instance:

```
echo '<strong>' .$element .'</strong><br>';
```

Do I need to always use single quotes for the HTML tags used inside of a PHP file? Or double quotes or no quotes?

Comment: single or double, not none. http://php.net/language.types.string

Comment: Let's not forget about [alternating between PHP and HTML](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php); `?><strong><?= $element ?></strong></p><?php`.

Comment: @dagon  whats the difference of using single quote or double quotes?

Comment: the answers to that are in the links above

Comment: Yes, see what Mario said. Don't trap static HTML inside PHP strings if you can help it.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you need to learn is that PHP *doesn't care about HTML*.

PHP doesn't understand that it's working with HTML, it just sees text and dutifully sends it to the browser. The *browser* then makes sense of it as HTML.

So, since `<strong>` is a string, it must be treated as a string. In other words, as `"<strong>"`, `'<strong>'` or even a [**heredoc**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

```
<<<HEREDOC
<strong>
HEREDOC;
```

(Probably not appropriate in this case :p)